# ignored fields when importing data using impdp

Tags: oracle, import, oracle12c, database-administration, impdp

I am trying to load it massively in my database and I noticed that by doing the following command if the table is empty it loads without problems, but if it has 1 record it ignores the entire table. am I using any parameter incorrectly?

```
impdp '/ as sysdba' directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=tst.bak remap_schema=bd1:bd1 
TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND CONTENT=DATA_ONLY DATA_OPTIONS=SKIP_CONSTRAINT_ERRORS
```

Thank you

Edit: as referred by @pifor follow the errors presented:

```
ORA-31693: Table data object "bd1"."CRM_PARTY" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (bd1.PK_CRM_PARTY) violated
```

Edit 2: as referred by @Alex Poole I confirm that the primary key is non deferrable

```
select deferrable, deferred
from user_constraints
where constraint_name = 'PK_CRM_PARTY';

NOT DEFERRABLE  |   IMMEDIATE
```

Comment: Is there any error ORA-XXX or IMPDP-XXX displayed ? If yes please post them.

Comment: added to topic. Ty

Comment: Is that a deferred constraint?

Comment: Your parameters looks correct to me. What is your 4 digits Oracle version ? In some versions this could be an Oracle bug.

Comment: Im using the Release 12.2.0.1.0

Comment: There are at least three bugs this could be (given that the constraint isn't deferrable). Have a look on My Oracle Support at bugs 16897998, 30296128 and 14735446 and see if those match, and if the workarounds help. You may need to raise a service request.

Comment: From the documentation:  "

Note:

Do not start Import as SYSDBA, except at the request of Oracle technical support. SYSDBA is used internally and has specialized functions; its behavior is not the same as for general users. "  (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-D34AA2AC-DD27-4557-98AC-CE9A3AC21E35 ).  Also,  'remap_schema=bd1:bd1' is pointless.  You would use remap_schema, to _change the schema, ie:  'remap_schema=bd1:xy2'.

Comment: the goal is to recover a database with a recent backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding the `IGNORE=Y` command solves my problem. This is not to say that there is no bug on Oracle's part.

```
impdp '/ as sysdba' directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=tst.bak remap_schema=bd1:bd1 
TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND CONTENT=DATA_ONLY DATA_OPTIONS=SKIP_CONSTRAINT_ERRORS IGNORE=Y
```